# Achilles Cassandra - Getting result of conditional update

Tags: cassandra

How to get response when performing a conditional update/delete from Achilles?
I tried using a custom ResultListener, but it doesn't always work correctly.

```
public class ResultListener implements LWTResultListener {

  private boolean applied;

  @Override
  public void onSuccess() {
     applied = true;
  }

  @Override
  public void onError(LWTResult lwtResult) {
    applied = false;
  }

  public boolean isApplied() {
    return applied;
  }
}
```

From my caller class, I call `isApplied()` but it seems that the `onSuccess` method is called asynchronously. The caller class doesn't see the updated value of `applied` field.

Comment: Edit: Alternative solution here: https://github.com/doanduyhai/Achilles/issues/343#issuecomment-409124764

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the problem with Cassandra/Achilles itself, but general problem with async programming - callback could be called at any point of time...

For your code there are 2 things:

- First, you need to understand if the callback was called or not - you may add another boolean variable that will be set by both `onSuccess` & `onError` to indicate that callback was called already. And your code need to check this variable before calling `isApplied`;
- Second - you need to guarantee that the change is visible by other parts of the code. You can add the `volatile` keyword to the declaration of `applied` variable (and to the declaration of variable described above).  This keyword will indicate that data could be changed by some other thread, and Java will enforce that data is always read from memory. [Following article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html) describes this in quite good details.